# SQL server job not listed under SQL Server Management studio jobs list

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, sql-agent-job

I have generated a script for the SQL Server Agent job that I created.

However, when I run the script even though the job is created successfully (able to verify it through sysjobs_view system view) but it does not get listed under SQL Server Agent jobs list.

Does anyone know what the issue could be?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried refreshing the Object Browser in SSMS?

Comment: I tried that. It's been such a long time since I started this thread. I can't really remember what the issue was. Sorry but thanks for all your responses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If dbrosier's suggestion to refresh the list doesn't work, I would check to see if you have a filter set on your jobs list. I would also wonder if it's a permissions issue, but in that case, you shouldn't be able to see any of the jobs and should get an error.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Since it's been a while when I had opened this thread. I am not sure what the exact issue was. I wish I could put the solution in here.